# How to query a datatable

Tags: c#, .net, datatable

I am using a XML file and the data from the XML is set into a dataset and user selected table is stored as a datatable.A query is been generated with filter criteria, grouping, aggregate function, expressions etc.Is it possible to query the datatable? 
I did come accross table.Select(filter criteria, sort) method.but kindly let me know how grouping, aggregate function and expression (eg: Column1 + Column2 as SumColumn) can be got.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, `table.Select(filterCriteria, sort)` is your only option without LINQ (I'm not a LINQ guru, so don't ask me what it can do).

Anytime I need something specific, I create/add that column to the DataTable.

```
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        // code that populates the table
        DataColumn c = table.Columns.Add("Column1 + Column2", typeof(int));
        int Sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < table.Rows.Count; i++) {
          r = table.Rows[i];
          int col1 = (int)r["Column1"];
          int col2 = (int)r["Column2"];
          int both = col1 + col2;
          Sum += both;
          r[c] = string.Format("{0}", both);
        }
        DataRow summaryRow = table.NewRow();
        summaryRow[c] = (int)((float)Sum / table.Rows.Count + 0.5); // add 0.5 to round
        table.Rows.Add(summaryRow);
```

HTH.

Comment: @ip2Code - thanx..Plz suggest a logic to do grouping and aggregate function(eg-sum(col1),avg(col2)) using C# code.

Comment: After you have built the table the way you need it, you'll have to loop through the entries to sum values and get averages.

Comment: I edited the code to give a more complete example of what I *think* you are after.

Comment: I was also thinking of looping it.since it is a generic tool, at  times the sum of the columns may vary(eg: (Col1+col2)/col3).thankz for giving me an idea how to proceed futhur.

Answer (score 2):

You could query the data using LINQ - assuming you are using a .Net Framework version that supports it. Check out [LINQ To Dataset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399399.aspx)

Comment: It should be a generic code to execute the filter criteria, grouping, aggregate function for all tables based on the User's selection of datasource and database.Can a generic LINQ query be created.

Comment: -Wat I mean by generic is that, tables/groupings/filter criteria details cannot be hard coded. I have a string with selected columns, filter criteria, grouping details for the query.but in LINQ the concatenation of string is not accepted ( eg: from <table> where <filter criteria>....is not executing as required)